# Counter won't update

Tags: python

beginner programmer with python here. I'm wondering why my "attempt" counter only updates once despite the loop continuing.

```
def login():
    attempt = 3
    username = input("Enter your username:\n> ")
    while True:
     if username in userNamePassword:
        password = input("Enter your password:\n> ")
        if userNamePassword[username] == password:
            print("Logged in")
            return True
        elif userNamePassword[username] != password:
            attempt -=1
            print("Sorry, the password is invalid. You have", attempt,"attempts remaining.")  
            login()
            if attempt == 0:
             print("Sorry, you have exhausted your password attempts. Please restart the process.")
             exit()
```

It only ever prints 1 as the attempt remaining however continues the loop asking for the user and pass once more. It's possibly a small, overlooked issue but I'm scratching my head here. Thanks

Comment: You should remove the recursive call to login().

Comment: remove `login()`

Comment: each time  attempt = 3, when call login()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove that `login()` call. When you call the function, the attemps will reset to 3. If you don't call it, you will stay in loop and the attemps will decrement. I recommend you, instead of `exit()` to use `break`

Comment: How silly of me! Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate if you could mark this answer as correct if it resolves your problem

Comment: I will do, there seems to be a time limit at the moment.

Comment: Missing 1 reputation point thats why :)